# Change various widths of all of a page at once (html)

Tags: html

I copied and past a text from MS-word to the front page then front page generated a lot cods there.

I put the generated cod in Persian site. Normally it gotta be like this:
http://porseman.org/showarticle.aspx?id=1079

But now it shows like this:
http://porseman.org/showarticle.aspx?id=1099

As you can see the width of the content is increased.
The question is how can I change it to normal without changing one by one? I mean, how can I change it at once? (Note that there is a lot of `width` properties)

```
    <body> 
<div class="WordSection1" dir="RTL">
    <p class="MsoNormal" dir="RTL" style="text-indent:0cm"><!--[if gte vml 1]><v:rect id="_x0000_s1035"
 style='position:absolute;margin-left:-28.5pt;margin-top:-27.75pt;width:323.25pt;
 height:36pt;z-index:251654144' strokecolor="white">
 <v:textbox>
<p class="MsoNormal" dir="RTL"><span dir="LTR">
<o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></span></p>
 </v:textbox>
</v:rect><![endif]--><![if !vml]><span style='mso-ignore:vglayout;position:
absolute;z-index:251654144;left:664px;top:-22px;width:437px;height:54px'><img
width=437 height=54 src="index17_files/image001.gif" alt="Text Box: &nbsp;&#13;&#10;"
v:shapes="_x0000_s1035"></span><![endif]></p>
    <![if !mso]><![endif]>&nbsp;<p>
    <span lang="AR-SA" style="font-size:13.0pt;font-family:
&quot;B Lotus&quot;">&nbsp;</span></p>
    <p class="af1" dir="RTL"><a name="_Toc298163545"><b>
    <span lang="AR-SA" style="font-size:12.5pt;font-family:Titr">فصل سوم</span></b></a></p>
    <p class="af1" dir="RTL"><a name="_Toc298163546"><b>
    <span lang="AR-SA" style="font-size:12.5pt;font-family:Titr">ارزيابي کارآمدي 
    انقلاب اسلامي</span></b></a></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" dir="RTL" style="text-indent: 14.2pt; line-height: 20.0pt">
    <span lang="AR-SA" style="font-size:13.0pt;
font-family:&quot;B Lotus&quot;">&nbsp;</span></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" dir="RTL" style="text-indent: 14.2pt; line-height: 20.0pt">
    <span lang="AR-SA" style="font-size:13.0pt;
font-family:&quot;B Lotus&quot;">اين فرماني است از بنده خدا، علي 
    اميرالمؤمنين[ع]، به مالك بن الحارث الاشتر، در پيماني كه با او مي‏‏نهد، 
    هنگامي كه او را فرمانروايي مصر داد؛ «... جِبَايه خَرَاجِهَا وَ جِهَادَ 
    عَدُوِّهَا وَ اِسْتِصْلاَحَ أَهْلِهَا وَ عِمَارَه بِلاَدِهَا؛ خراج آنجا را 
    گرد آورد و با دشمنانش پيكار كند و كار مردمش را اصلاح و شهرهايش را آباد 
    سازد.»</span><a name="_ftnref1" title style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline; text-underline: single" href="#_ftn1"><sup><span dir="LTR" lang="AR-SA" style="font-family: B Lotus"><sup><span style="font-size: 14.0pt; font-family: 'Times New Roman',serif">[1]</span></sup></span></sup></a></p>
    <h2 dir="RTL"><a name="_Toc297625141">
    <span lang="FA" style="font-size: 11.5pt; font-family: Mitra">مقدمه</span></a></h2>
    <p class="MsoNormal" dir="RTL" style="text-indent: 14.2pt; line-height: 20.0pt">
    <span lang="AR-SA" style="font-size:13.0pt;
font-family:&quot;B Lotus&quot;">بي‌گمان انقلاب اسلامي ايران يکي از مهم‌ترين 
    تحوّلات سياسي قرن بيستم و نقطه عطف مهمي در انقلاب‌هاي جهان به شمار مي‌آيد. 
    از مهم‌ترين وجوه تمايز اين انقلاب از ساير انقلاب‌هاي جهان، ابتناي آن بر دين 
    و داعيه اداره جامعه بر اساس آموزه‌هاي اصيل اسلام ناب محمد‌ي</span><span lang="AR-SA" style="font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;B Lotus&quot;">(صلي‌الله‌عليه‌وآله‌وسلم)</span><span lang="AR-SA" style="font-size:13.0pt;font-family:&quot;B Lotus&quot;"> 
    است. با گذشت بيش از سه دهه از شکل‌گيري نظام جمهوري اسلامي و استقرار نهادهاي 
    حکومتي، علل و عوامل متعددي تبيين و تدوين کارنامه نظام را در حوزه‌ها و ابعاد 
    مختلف ضروري ساخته که مهم‌ترين آنها به قرار ذيل است:</span></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" dir="RTL" style="text-indent: 14.2pt; line-height: 20.0pt">
    <span lang="AR-SA" style="font-size:13.0pt;
font-family:&quot;B Lotus&quot;">1. ضرورت پاسخگويي به تبليغات و شبهه‌افکني 
    دشمنان بر محور ناکارآمدي نظام اسلامي در دنياي مدرن. </span></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" dir="RTL" style="text-indent: 14.2pt; line-height: 20.0pt">
    <span lang="AR-SA" style="font-size:13.0pt;
font-family:&quot;B Lotus&quot;">2. ضرروت پاسخگويي به دغدغه‌هاي نسل جوان.</span></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" dir="RTL" style="text-indent: 14.2pt; line-height: 21.0pt">
    <span lang="AR-SA" style="font-size:13.0pt;
font-family:&quot;B Lotus&quot;">3. ضرورت اثبات کارآمدي دين در عصر جديد. </span>
    </p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" dir="RTL" style="text-indent: 14.2pt; line-height: 21.0pt">
    <span lang="AR-SA" style="font-size:13.0pt;
font-family:&quot;B Lotus&quot;">4. ضرورت تحکيم مقبوليت مردمي نظام اسلامي.
    </span></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" dir="RTL" style="text-indent: 14.2pt; line-height: 21.0pt">
    <span lang="AR-SA" style="font-size:13.0pt;
font-family:&quot;B Lotus&quot;">5. لزوم ارزيابي نقاط قوّت و ضعف نهادها و 
    دستگاه‌هاي حکومتي. </span></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" dir="RTL" style="text-indent: 14.2pt; line-height: 21.0pt">
    <span lang="AR-SA" style="font-size:13.0pt;
font-family:&quot;B Lotus&quot;">6. ضرورت ثبت مجاهدت‌ها، جانفشاني</span><span lang="AR-SA" dir="LTR" style="font-size:
13.0pt;font-family:&quot;B Lotus&quot;">‎</span><span lang="AR-SA" style="font-size:13.0pt;font-family:&quot;B Lotus&quot;">ها، 
    ايثارها و تلاش‌هاي صورت گرفته پس از حاکميت نظام اسلامي. </span></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" dir="RTL" style="text-indent: 14.2pt; line-height: 21.0pt">
    <span lang="AR-SA" style="font-size:13.0pt;
font-family:&quot;B Lotus&quot;">7. ضرورت تأمين منابع مستند براي تسهيل پژوهش‌هاي 
    مرتبط با انقلاب</span><span lang="AR-SA" dir="LTR" style="font-size:
13.0pt;font-family:&quot;B Lotus&quot;">‎</span><span lang="AR-SA" style="font-size:13.0pt;font-family:&quot;B Lotus&quot;">اسلامي.
    </span></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" dir="RTL" style="text-indent: 14.2pt; line-height: 21.0pt">
    <span lang="AR-SA" style="font-size:13.0pt;
font-family:&quot;B Lotus&quot;">8. ضرورت فراهم ساختن بستر مناسب جهت ارائه 
    الگوهاي نوين از کارآمدي و پيشرفت در راستاي تمدن‌سازي.</span><a name="_ftnref2" title style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline; text-underline: single" href="#_ftn2"><sup><span dir="LTR" lang="AR-SA" style="font-family: B Lotus"><sup><span style="font-size: 14.0pt; font-family: 'Times New Roman',serif">[2]</span></sup></span></sup></a></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" dir="RTL" style="text-indent: 14.2pt; line-height: 21.0pt">
    <span lang="AR-SA" style="font-size:13.0pt;
font-family:&quot;B Lotus&quot;">بر اين اساس حضرت امام(ره) از آغاز، همواره بر 
    ارائه گزارش عملکردهاي دولت و نظام اسلامي به مردم تأکيد فراوان داشتند: 
    «کارهايي را که جمهوري اسلامي براي مردم در اين چند سال با اين گرفتاري‌ها که 
    دارند انجام دادند، اين بايد گفته بشود که مردم بفهمند که در اين چند سال با 
    همه گرفتاري‌ها چه شده برايشان، چه کرده دولت. اين يک مطلبي بود که بايد عرض 
    کنم که ما قصور کرديم در آن و بايد جبران بکنيم».</span><a name="_ftnref3" title style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline; text-underline: single" href="#_ftn3"><sup><span dir="LTR" lang="AR-SA" style="font-family: B Lotus"><sup><span style="font-size: 14.0pt; font-family: 'Times New Roman',serif">[3]</span></sup></span></sup></a></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" dir="RTL" style="text-indent: 14.2pt; line-height: 21.0pt">
    <span lang="AR-SA" style="font-size:13.0pt;
font-family:&quot;B Lotus&quot;">و مقام معظم رهبري(دام ظله)‌ در باب کارآمدي نظام 
    اسلامي و ضرورت افزايش آن، چنين مي‌فرمايند:</span></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" dir="RTL" style="text-indent: 14.2pt; line-height: 21.0pt">
    <span lang="AR-SA" style="font-size:13.0pt;
font-family:&quot;B Lotus&quot;">«آنچه ما مسئولان احتياج داريم، اين است که 
    کارآمدي خود و نظام را افزايش دهيم. کارآمدي، هم بايد در جهت تحقق خواست‏ها و 
    اهداف اسلامي باشد و هم در جهت پياده شدن و عيني شدن ارزشها؛ در جامعه بايد 
    بيشتر به سمت اسلامي شدن، مسلمان شدن و مؤمنانه و مسلمانانه زندگي کردن برويم، 
    بايد به سمت زندگي علوي برويم. بايد روح زندگي علوي؛ يعني عدالت، تقوا، 
    پارسايي، پاکدامني، بي‌پروايي در راه خدا و ميل و شوق به مجاهدت در راه خدا را 
    در خودمان زنده کنيم؛ بايد به سمت اينها برويم؛ اين اساس کار ما است. در آن 
    صورت، کارآمدي جمهوري اسلامي هم مضاعف خواهد شد؛ چون مشکل اساسي‌اي که ممکن است 
    براي نظام اسلامي پيش بيايد، کارآمدي در نگاه جهاني است؛ بگويند آيا توانستند 
    اين کار را بکنند؟ توانستد آن کار را بکنند؟ اگر ما قدم به قدم تحوّل دروني خود 
    را جدّي بگيريم و پيش ببريم و پايبندي خود را به ارزشها و اصول خود عملاً نشان 
    دهيم، کارايي و توفيقات ما هم بيشتر خواهد شد. البته دشمنان نمي‌خواهند؛ جنجال 
    و هياهو مي‌کنند؛ اهميتي هم ندارد.»</span><a name="_ftnref4" title style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline; text-underline: single" href="#_ftn4"><sup><span dir="LTR" lang="AR-SA" style="font-family: B Lotus"><sup><span style="font-size: 14.0pt; font-family: 'Times New Roman',serif">[4]</span></sup></span></sup></a></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" dir="RTL" style="text-indent: 14.2pt; line-height: 21.0pt">
    <span lang="AR-SA" style="font-size:13.0pt;
font-family:&quot;B Lotus&quot;">در بخش اول از مباحث کارآمدي نظام اسلامي، کلياتي 
    پيرامون ماهيت و عناصر کارآمدي نظام سياسي و سازوکارهاي تحقق آن در نظام اسلامي 
    بيان گرديد. در اين قسمت تلاش مي‏شود به صورت عيني کارآمدي نظام اسلامي از 
    رهگذر دستاوردهاي انقلاب اسلامي و نظام مقدس جمهوري اسلامي مورد بررسي و دقت 
    نظر قرار گيرد. قبل از ورود به دستاوردها ابتدا لازم است اين پرسش مطرح شود که؛ 
    در ارزيابي کارآمدي انقلاب اسلامي از چه روشي مي‏توان استفاده کرد؟ مهمترين 
    ملاک‏ها در ارزيابي آثار و دستاوردهاي انقلاب اسلامي کدامند؟</span></p>
    <p class="MsoNormal" dir="RTL" style="text-indent: 14.2pt; line-height: 21.0pt">
    <span lang="AR-SA" style="font-size:13.0pt;
font-family:&quot;B Lotus&quot;">قضاوت پيرامون موفقيت و کارآمدي يک پديده خاص اعم 
    از کشور، نظام سياسي يا انقلاب براساس سه شاخصه «اهداف»، «امکانات» و «موانع» 
    آن پديده مشخص مي‏گردد. هر قدر پديده‏اي با توجه به سه شاخصه مذکور در تحقق 
    اهدافش موفق باشد به همان مقدار تواناتر و کارآمدتر است. افزون بر اين چهار 
    نظريه شاخص در باب سنجش کارآمدي وجود دارد</span><a name="_ftnref5" title style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline; text-underline: single" href="#_ftn5"><sup><span dir="LTR"><sup><span style="font-size: 14.0pt; font-family: 'Times New Roman',serif">[5]</span></sup></span></sup></a><span lang="AR-SA" style="font-size:13.0pt;font-family:&quot;B Lotus&quot;"> 
    که عبارتند از: </span></p>
    <h2 dir="RTL" style="line-height: 21.0pt">&nbsp;</h2>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: This just in, Frontpage generates cods.
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Vgx2R1cBaPs/Th4u7q-vLkI/AAAAAAAAAZ0/izuM6rSKMEY/s1600/cod_fish.jpg

Comment: Wow this code is so clean. I am overwhelmed

Comment: I love how the edit left the 'cods' intact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frontpage is a blight on the web, and should never be used by anyone.

That said, there is a [Frontpage Code Cleaner](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/frontpage-code-cleaner.shtml) you can use to help clean up its mess.

Don't rely on it blindly though.

Be sure to check what comes out of the cleaner, and good luck!

Comment: Never mind FrontPage. Copying from MS-Word to a webpage! Aaaaarghhh!

Comment: @MrLister : i think the level or horror is comparable to say the least, both generate attrocious markup code.
A nice little remnant of the days when microsoft thought they could dictate web standards -_-